# Can't make the content of the timer update every second

Tags: javascript, setinterval

In this code, I create a div element and append it to 'timer' div. I would like to primarily clear the div element to display seconds value every second. However, I get seconds only ONE time. I don't understand how to fix it. I added a check to get rid of child elements of timer(if they exist which of course will happen when many elements will be created). How to make the content of the timer div update every second?

```
let timer = document.getElementById('timer');
let time = setInterval(() => {
  while (timer.firstChild) {
    timer.removeChild(timer.firstChild);
  }
  timer.append(document.createElement('div').textContent = `${new Date().getSeconds()}`)
}, 1000);
```

Comment: `In this code, I create a div element and append it to 'timer' div. ` no, not exactly. You create a `<div>`, set its `textContent`, immediately throw it away and `append` the string to `timer`. Why don't you just use `timer.innerHTML` to set the time? Or even `timer.textContent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code appears to be working, try this snippet.

```js
let timer = document.getElementById('timer');

let time = setInterval(() => {
  while (timer.firstChild) {
    timer.removeChild(timer.firstChild);
  }

  timer.append(
    document.createElement('div').textContent = `
        ${new Date().getSeconds()}                
  `)
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Comment: The div created is unused, as the assignment just return the value of `new Date().getSeconds()`, so you could just assign directly to `timer.textContent` and remove the need for the while loop

Comment: Yes, I see that too, I'm just pointing out to the OP that their code is working as is